# How to neatly query corresponding object array items?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have an array of objects that'll be used for some process.

```
var x = new List<MyObject>() { new MyObject(), new MyObject(), ... }.ToArray();
```

After the process, it returns an array of results corresponding to each of the input objects.

```
var y = MyProcess(x); // returns List<MyResult>
```

Now, my question is how can I query a list of results with a given condition and the corresponding input objects?

For example, if `y[2].IsOkay` is `false`, I want to obtain both `x[2]` and `y[2]` in another array.
And the objects in array x and y don't have a reference key except the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can use [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/dd267698.aspx) to pair them up:

```
var pairs = x.Zip(y, (a, b) => new { a, b })
             .Where(pair => !pair.b.IsOkay)
             .ToArray();
```

You can change the delegate passed to `Zip` to compose the two values differently if you want - for example, using a named type instead of the anonymous type I've got above.

Comment: `Zip` was always difficult for me to understand. Here's the MSDN documentation, and it helps.. a bit. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx